# Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module

Tags: android, linux

I'm getting the error *"Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module."* when I set up the AVD in Android studio.

Although I installed required package e.g HAXM & system images.
And although I enable vt-x in BIOS Security.

Comment: HAXM is useless for linux. It can be used only in Windows. About the problem, you did not `ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module`, did you?

Comment: This sounds like a question to post in either [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) as it does not seem to have much to do with programming which is [the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I'm working in only windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this error by following bellow step..

1. go to your sdk folder "C:\Users\radia\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk".from there you can access extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager this path.
   2.install this executable file "intelhaxm-android".
2. If Needed, Restart the machine.

It Will Work.

Comment: its already installed in my machine and still i am getting this above problem,what should  i do now?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue, I installed required package e.g HAXM and also enabled vt-x in BIOS Security, still getting the same issue.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 14):

These simple steps solved my issue

1. Go the system BIOS. For thos who dont know how to get into bios- Restart computer- continusly press F2 (In my computer, it may be diffrent in yours)
2. Enable Intel Virtualization Technology (also known as Intel VT) or AMD-V depending on the brand of the processor. The virtualization extensions may be labeled Virtualization Extensions, Vanderpool or various other names depending on the OEM and system BIOS.
3. Save

Answer (score 8):

I am working on Linux,Fedora 27 and I had same problem so I did this Solution:

1. Restart your computer and Go to the system BIOS (press Del or F2 (It is different in each system,my system is Del key))
2. In Advanced tab Choose,Cpu configuration and Enabled Intel Virtualization Technology,Finally Save the Changes and Restart Your Computer.

Answer (score 3):

In AMD processor, I found the `Virtualization Technology` as `SVM`. After running the boot menu, search for `SVM` (which should be under CPU configuration) and make `SVM Mode` as `Enabled`

Follow the link for more details: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1038245/

Answer (score 2):

Sudo mknod /dev/kvm c 10 232;

sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:rwx /dev/kvm

sudo chmod -R 0777 /dev/kvm

-- Restart android studio --